# bind9: example.com works, www.example.com doesnt, and how to block urls

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, url, block

1)
I was following a guide to setup bind again after I formatted to Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS.
http://doc.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/serverguide/C/dns-configuration.html#dns-primarymaster-configuration

I can get my domain example.com to resolve but I want "www.example.com" to resolve to the actual domain on the web.

I don't have a webserver setup on my domain at the moment so I would rather it resolve properly.

So "ping example.com" works and resolves to my local address but "ping www.example.com" gives "ping: unknown host www.example.com".

Here is the file db.example.com,

```
;
; BIND data file for example.com
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.example.com. root.example.com. (
                              9         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.example.com.
@       IN      A       10.11.12.1
;www    IN      A       10.11.12.1
ns      IN      A       10.11.12.1
```

I tried adding in a www entry but it only resolves to the same local ip as example.com so I commented it out.

2)
I am planning on adding all of the urls from the ad block site http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt to bind so as to block them on my network.

So how would I add this list to bind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried adding in a www entry but it only resolves to the same local ip as example.com so I commented it out.

Well, that's why it doesn't work. Create a proper A resource record for `www`, increase the serial number of your zone file and reload the zone.

You should also read up on the basics of DNS e. g. in [DNS for Rocket Scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/).

> I am planning on adding all of the urls from the ad block site
>   http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt to bind so as to block them on
>   my network.

BIND is not really meant for this kind of manipulation. This said you can create a `static-stub` zone in newer versions of BIND to manipulate DNS entries. See http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.8/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2591396 for details.

Comment: "Create a proper A resource record for www", not sure what you mean, could you explain further or give an example

Comment: Uncomment the line `www IN A 10.11.12.1` and read up on it in DNS for Rocket Scientists.

Comment: Ok I can hardcode it to the IP of www.example.com while remaining the master for example.com.  Secondly, what do you mean bind wasn't meant for blocking urls.  Its a domain name server, what else am I supposed to use?  I browse with chrome and its adblock isn't as good as ff.  Using hosts file slows down windows.

Comment: BIND was built to be an auhtoritative name server and caching resolver. Manipulating DNS entries, e. g. overwriting zone-data of the forwarders (the name servers the caching resolver will get its data from) was not a primary concern. That's why getting that list to use with BIND is rather tedious.